# C# Windows Service latest technology

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

All,

I have been writting Windows Services for a while in C# deriving from ServiceBase.
So far my services are hosted in servers where they usually listen to message queues and process messages.

Is there a new way of creating such services in WCF ?

Thanks,

MK

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of message queues? MSMQ, something else, or something custom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Check out [Windows Process Activation Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734677.aspx).

From what I understand, it's very much like how you used to host remoting objects under IIS, but with WAS, you don't need to involve the whole huge IIS stack like you used to.

Comment: I've also been hearing a lot about Windows Server App Fabric.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Message Queuing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing) would seem to be what you'd want though there are some offshoots like [BizTalk Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_BizTalk_Server) that may use similar stuff.  Just to toss out an idea or two.

Answer (score 0):

I've started using an open source project called [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) to easily create applications that run as either a Windows Service or a console app for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I've also been hearing a lot about **Windows Server App Fabric**.  Here is a quick blurb from the [App Fabric white paper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/F/8/7F8BD8A0-EB05-4DB5-A5A4-DD1D3C909A0A/Introducing_Windows_Server_AppFabric.pdf).

`AppFabric Hosting Services (originally code-named “Dublin”) doesn’t create some entirely new hosting infrastructure. Instead, it builds on what’s already provided by Internet Information Services (IIS) and Windows Process Activation Service (WAS). On this foundation, AppFabric Hosting Services adds extra capabilities for running and managing WCF services, including workflow services. Figure 7 illustrates this idea.`

[Windows App Fabric Home](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx)